# Visual Basic Default Property vs C# Property

Tags: c#, vb.net, properties, indexer

I'm converting Visual Basic.Net code to C# in my project. But I have some doubts on how to convert Visual Basic default property to C#. The first option that comes to me are the indexers. Lets imagine the next code in Visual Basic

```vb
Public Class MyClass
Dim MyHash as Hashtable

Public sub New()
    MyHash = New Hashtable()
    MyHash.Add("e1",1)
    MyHash.Add("e2",2)
    MyHash.Add("e3",3)
End Sub

Defaul Propery MyDefProp(ByVal key as string) as Object
  Get
    Return MyHash(key)
  End Get

  Set(ByVal ObjectToStore As Object)
    MyHash(key) = ObjectToStore
  End Set
End Property
```

Converted this to C#:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private Hashtable MyHash;

    public MyClass()
    {
        MyHash = new Hashtable();
        MyHash.Add("A1",1);
        MyHash.Add("A2",2);
        MyHash.Add("A3",3);
    }

    public object this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return MyHash[key]; 
        }

        set
        {
            MyHash[key] = value;
        }
    }     
}
```

Am I correct on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct.

The only difference is that the VB.Net version also creates a named indexed property; C# does not support named indexed properties.

Answer (score 1):

While C# does support the default property syntax, your indexer will meet that need nicely.

Comment: Indexers _are_ default properties.

Comment: My VB is a bit rusty, but I don't think that you are forced to have an indexed default property.  For example the Text property was the default for TextBox, and it is not an indexed probperty.

Comment: VB.NET supports 'indexed' properties that are not the default property.  Properties can have an arbitrary number of arguments, unlike C#.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022 you absolutely can index a class by name in C#. Just add this to your class definition:

```
public object this[string key]
{
   get { return this.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(this, new object[0]); }
}
```

You can add a setter to this and your no longer stuck with just dot notation